# using Facebook api to access recent activity section

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

A user's wall has sections titled "Recent Activity" which include links to posts that the user has liked or commented on, plus recently used applications, new friends etc.

Is there a programmatic way to access this information using Facebook api or something else? 
I noticed this info isn't included in user feed.

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this the same with user feed? If so you can query the graph API by calling:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<facebookID>/feed?access_token=<your access token>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this information isn't available through any API that Facebook offers.